# Computing the spectral norms of ~1m Hermitian matrices: `numpy.linalg.norm` is too slow

Tags: python, numpy, cython, linear-algebra, numba

I would like to calculate the spectral norms of *N* 8x8 Hermitian  matrices, with *N* being close to 1E6. As an example, take these 1 million random complex 8x8 matrices:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.random.rand(8,8,1e6)  + 1j*np.random.rand(8,8,1e6)
```

It currently takes me almost 10 seconds using `numpy.linalg.norm`:

```
np.linalg.norm(array, ord=2, axis=(0,1))
```

I tried using the Cython code below, but this gave me only a negligible performance improvement:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

np.import_array()

DTYPE = np.complex64

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def function(np.ndarray[np.complex64_t, ndim=3] Array):
    assert Array.dtype == DTYPE
    cdef int shape0 = Array.shape[2]
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] normarray = np.zeros(shape0, dtype=np.float32)
    normarray = np.linalg.norm(Array, ord=2, axis=(0, 1))
    return normarray
```

I also tried numba and some other scipy functions (such as      `scipy.linalg.svdvals`) to calculate the singular values of these matrices. Everything is still too slow.

Is it not possible to make this any faster? Is numpy already optimized to the extent that no speed gains are possible by using Cython or numba? Or is my code highly inefficient and I am doing something fundamentally wrong?

I noticed that only two of my CPU cores are 100% utilized while doing the calculation. With that in mind, I looked at these previous StackOverflow questions:

- [why isn't numpy.mean multithreaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617973/why-isnt-numpy-mean-multithreaded)
- [Why does multiprocessing use only a single core after I import numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639779/why-does-multiprocessing-use-only-a-single-core-after-i-import-numpy)
- [multithreaded blas in python/numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260068/multithreaded-blas-in-python-numpy/7645939#7645939) (didn't help)

and several others, but unfortunately I still don't have a solution.

I considered splitting my array into smaller chunks, and processing these in parallel (perhaps on the GPU using CUDA). Is there a way within numpy/Python to do this? I don't yet know where the bottleneck is in my code, i.e. whether it is CPU or memory-bound, or perhaps something different.

Comment: You will not see any performance benefit from Cython or numba if you are simply using them to call a numpy function. Cython and numba have no awareness of the internal workings of numpy, and can't do anything to optimize numpy functions - you would have to write your own low-level loops over the array to compute the norm.

Comment: This calculation scales linearly with `N`.  Simply generating the array takes 1/4 the time the norm takes.  And on my relatively old machine, 1e6 is too large to even generate the array.  So a big part of the speed issue is the shear size of the data.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I guess I cannot beat numpy then except rewriting everything on a very low-level loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging into the code for `np.linalg.norm`, I've deduced, that for these parameters, it is finding the maximum of matrix singular values over the N dimension

First generate a small sample array.  Make `N` the first dimension to eliminate a `rollaxis` operation:

```
In [268]: N=10; A1 = np.random.rand(N,8,8)+1j*np.random.rand(N,8,8)

In [269]: np.linalg.norm(A1,ord=2,axis=(1,2))
Out[269]: 
array([ 5.87718306,  5.54662999,  6.15018125,  5.869058  ,  5.80882818,
        5.86060462,  6.04997992,  5.85681085,  5.71243196,  5.58533323])
```

the equivalent operation:

```
In [270]: np.amax(np.linalg.svd(A1,compute_uv=0),axis=-1)
Out[270]: 
array([ 5.87718306,  5.54662999,  6.15018125,  5.869058  ,  5.80882818,
        5.86060462,  6.04997992,  5.85681085,  5.71243196,  5.58533323])
```

same values, and same time:

```
In [271]: timeit np.linalg.norm(A1,ord=2,axis=(1,2))
1000 loops, best of 3: 398 µs per loop
In [272]: timeit np.amax(np.linalg.svd(A1,compute_uv=0),axis=-1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 389 µs per loop
```

And most of the time spent in `svd`, which produces an (N,8) array:

```
In [273]: timeit np.linalg.svd(A1,compute_uv=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 366 µs per loop
```

So if you want to speed up the `norm`, you have look further into speeding up this `svd`.  `svd` uses  `np.linalg._umath_linalg` functions - that is a `.so` file - compiled.

The `c` code is in https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/97c35365beda55c6dead8c50df785eb857f843f0/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src

It sure looks like this is the fastest you'll get.  There's no Python level loop.  Any looping is in that `c` code, or the `lapack` function it calls.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at this. I still wonder why Numpy does not use more than one cpu core . I assume, that for this particular task, Numpy is just unable to do so?

Comment: Whether or not `np.linalg.svd` uses multiple cores when performing SVD will depend on which LAPACK shared library you are linked against. For example if you link against OpenBLAS then you will probably see it using multiple cores. However the parallelization would be within each 8x8 submatrix rather than over the vector of N matrices, so it's unlikely to make a huge difference in terms of performance.

Answer (score 3):

`np.linalg.norm(A, ord=2)` computes the spectral norm by finding the largest singular value using SVD. However, since your 8x8 submatrices are Hermitian, their largest singular values will be equal to the maximum of their absolute eigenvalues ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm)):

```
import numpy as np

def random_symmetric(N, k):
    A = np.random.randn(N, k, k)
    A += A.transpose(0, 2, 1)
    return A

N = 100000
k = 8
A = random_symmetric(N, k)

norm1 = np.abs(np.linalg.eigvalsh(A)).max(1)
norm2 = np.linalg.norm(A, ord=2, axis=(1, 2))

print(np.allclose(norm1, norm2))
# True
```

Eigendecomposition on a Hermitian matrix is quite a bit faster than SVD:

```
In [1]: %%timeit A = random_symmetric(N, k)
np.linalg.norm(A, ord=2, axis=(1, 2))
   ....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 1.54 s per loop

In [2]: %%timeit A = random_symmetric(N, k)
np.abs(np.linalg.eigvalsh(A)).max(1)
   ....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 757 ms per loop
```

Comment: The spectral norm of a hermitian matrix is the maximum of the absolute values of the eigenvalues, whether or not the matrix is positive definite.

Comment: This indeed almost halves the required calculation time, thank you. Unrelated to this: Why did you edit the original question? To make it look nicer or for some badges?

Comment: The main reason I edited your question was to try to make the title and the tags reflect the nature of the problem a bit more more clearly, rather than your attempted solutions. SO Q&As should ideally be useful resources for other people looking for solutions to similar problems. If I was googling for a fast way to compute the spectral norms of a large number of matrices then I would have a much better chance of finding this question with the current title rather than the old one that referred to Cython and Numba. Anyway, glad I could help.