# How array size affects numpy matrix operation execution time and CPU usage

Tags: python, numpy

My question is about the following code:

```
%%time
import numpy as np
n_elems = 95
n_repeats = 100000
for i in range(n_repeats):
    X = np.random.rand(n_elems, n_elems)
    y = np.random.rand(n_elems)
    _ = X.dot(y)
```

I run this in iPython (version `6.2.1`) with Python `3.5.5` and numpy version `1.14.0` on an 8-core machine.

I get the following output:

```
CPU times: user 8.93 s, sys: 439 ms, total: 9.37 s  
Wall time: 8.79 s
```

When `n_elems` is set between `1` and `95`, the CPU and wall time are roughly equivalent. In addition, the CPU usage of the process (as seen using `top`) only goes up to `100%`.

However, when `n_elems` is set to `96`, I get the following:

```
CPU times: user 39.4 s, sys: 1min 28s, total: 2min 8s  
Wall time: 16.2 s
```

There is now a noticeable difference between the CPU and wall time. Also, the CPU usage reaches close to `800%`.
Similar behaviour is observed for larger values of `n_elems`.

I think this is because at a certain array size the numpy operation becomes multithreaded.
Could someone clarify this?
Also is there a way to restrict CPU usage of the process to `100%`.

Comment: 8-cores here as well, but I can't see a significant difference of the timings between your cases. And CPU usage is 800% in both cases.

Comment: For my use case, I switched to using `np.einsum` (instead of `np.dot`) since this is single-threaded. There is a slight increase in execution time but it no longer uses multiple processors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some numpy operations (e.g. `numpy.dot`) use BLAS which can execute in parallel.

Other numpy operations (e.g. `numpy.einsum`) are implemented directly in C and execute serially.

See [why isn't numpy.mean multithreaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617973/why-isnt-numpy-mean-multithreaded) for more details.

To restrict execution of `numpy.dot` to a single thread irregardless of array size, I had to set the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to 1 before importing numpy.

I found the following helpful:
[How do you stop numpy from multithreading?](http://How%20do%20you%20stop%20numpy%20from%20multithreading?)
[Limit number of threads in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791550/limit-number-of-threads-in-numpy/31622299#31622299)