# How to make numpy.take or slice multithread?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

I tested the code for both numpy.take and slice as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import time


a = np.random.randn(4000000,500)
b = np.arange(0, len(a))
t1 = time.time()
for i in range(10):
        a[b!=2]
t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)

t1 = time.time()
for i in range(10):
        a.take(b!=2, axis=0)
t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)
```

I checked my CPU and the most of them are idle. Only 1 CPU is used. As a result, the timing is very slow.

```
65.91494154930115
47.01117730140686
```

It seems to me that slicing is a parallelizable operation. Why is numpy not parallelizing it? Is it that numpy doens't support parallelizable slice or that I need to use some special function in numpy?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617973/why-isnt-numpy-mean-multithreaded

Comment: I wouldn't call this `slicing`.  `slicing` is basic indexing, using notation like `a[1:100,:]`, which returns a `view` and is quite fast, since it doesn't have to copy any data.  With `b!=2`, you are doing advanced indexing, with a boolean mask.  It does copy data, in this case all elements except one row.