# how to pass one element of an array to a process in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to pass each element of an array to a process by multiprocessing in python. How can I do it?
For example, I have `a[i]` as an array and want to send `a[0]` to core 1, `a[1]` to core 2,....
Is there any way to do it in python?

Comment: What you're looking for is subprocess, pool, and map. Look at the very first example in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @Roy2012 My problem is that I have 3 array with large size and I don't want to pass whole of arrays to cores because it will be time consumer. For example, I want to send a[0], b[0] and T[0] to one core, a[1], b[1] and T[1] to another core, .... This way that you said, send whole of array to all cores.

Answer (score 0):

CPython (the standard python implementation) has something called the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) ,as Gabriel Grant write in this answer [Python threads all executing on a single core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496680/python-threads-all-executing-on-a-single-core) each time a request to make a new thread is made, the interpreter actually calls into the operating system’s libraries and kernel to generate a new thread. 
so you can use multi-threading to use multitask at the same time but you can't force wich core will be executed

Comment: how is this relevant to [process based parallelism](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) that the OP seems to be talking about?

Comment: @Belhadjer Samir My problem is that I have 3 array with large size and I don't want to pass whole of arrays to cores because it will be time consumer. For example, I want to send a[0], b[0] and T[0] to one core, a[1], b[1] and T[1] to another core, ....

Comment: Threads uniquely run in the same unique memory heap. Whereas Processes run in separate memory heaps.

Comment: @Belhadjer Samir So can't I do it in multiprocessing? I have to do it in multi-threading?

Comment: @Ehsan i suggest to you to use numpy it is very fast than simpe array and you can use multithreading if you need it check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617973/why-isnt-numpy-mean-multithreaded